# How do I add hamstache to Ack searches?

Tags: haml, mustache, ack

Ack isn't searching my .hamstache files. How do I get it included in searches?

My .ackrc file looks like this:

```
--type-add
ruby=haml

--type-add
ruby=slim

--type-add
js=.coffee

--type-set
coffee=.coffee

--type-add
haml=hamstache
```

When I run a search on the project I get this message:

```
ack: --type-add: Type "haml" does not exist, creating with "hamstache" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is just a warning, not an error.  You can safely ignore it.

`--type-add` is for adding to an extension that already exists.  You want `--type-set` for the first time you specify an extension for a filetype.

Be careful with `--type-set`, though, because it will overwrite whatever is set.  For example, if you do `--type-set=ruby=.rubytest`, then then *only* extension ack will recognize is `.rubytest`.

ack 2.0 (in alpha) has a debug option to make this easier and clearer to debug.

Comment: How would you deal with potential future releases of ack that add new file types, without getting the warning and without overwriting them?

Comment: I don't know that there's a solution to that.  It's always possible to get updated or new filetypes in future releases of ack.  That said, ack 2.0 makes it easier to manage your filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you’re missing the `.` before the `hamstache` file extension.

Comment: That's not it.  Ack 1.x doesn't care either way.